# unable open raw socket in a linux container even after setting cap_net_raw

Tags: c, linux, docker, kubernetes, raw-sockets

I am running a code which opens a raw socket inside a docker container with kubernetes as the orchestrator.

Following is my sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <netinet/ip.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{  
        //Create a raw socket
        int s = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_SCTP);

        if(s == -1)
        {
                perror("Failed to create socket");
                exit(1);
        }

}
```

On running the code as a non-root user in my container/pod, I got this error.

```
./rawSocTest
Failed to create socket: Operation not permitted
```

This is obvious as it requires root level privileges to open a raw socket. This I corrected by setting capability cap_net_raw.

```
getcap rawSocTest
rawSocTest = cap_net_raw+eip
```

Now when I run it again. I am getting a different error.

```
./rawSocTest
bash: ./rawSocTest: Permission denied
```

As per my understanding, setting the capability should have fixed my issue. Am I missing something here? or Is this a known limitation of container?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might depend on your Dockerfile. Can you show it? If you don't do anything to run under a different user, your container should run as root and have the access needed.

Comment: I have created a user and group inside my dockerfile and set ownership to this user and group after copying binary into the image(base image is a CentOS nano image). Also capability setting is handled in dockerfile after this step. In the manfest file for kubernetes deployment, the security context section, I have set runAsuser and provided the user id of the user. I logged on to the pod and verified the same.

Comment: Please dump the effective caps of your process inside the container, `grep CapEff /proc/self/status`. I suspect that by switching to a non-root user and not setting the file capabilities of your binary you end up as the "black knight" from the Python movie without arms and legs, that is, without the necessary effective cap(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I need to set capabilities in the container's security context section of the kubernetes deployment. I added NET_RAW capability to allow raw socket creation. I was under the impression that just adding capability cap_net_raw to the process while building would suffice. But my understanding turns out to be wrong.

I did some study and cleaned up the deployment solution. I added NET_RAW in the allowed capability section of my pod security policy. Then created a role and rolebinding. Through rolebinding linked it to the service account in the namespace where my pod will be deployed. Then used this serviceAccount in the pod deployment. Not sure if this is a good solution.

Comment: Could it be that you fell into the gap between "file caps" (set on a binary), "bounded caps" (set on the initial container process) and "effective caps"? The effective caps are usually cleared when switching to a non-root user, so you might end with the capabilities specified for the container and set as bounded caps, but you don't have the effective caps without which your socket syscall will fail.

Comment: "_Not sure if this is a good solution._" As far as I can tell from my own experience, this is the correct solution within Kubernetes' security framework.

Answer (score 1):

I ran it using user kubernetes-admin

Adding the sample deployment file for container definition to what was stated earlier

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpd-deployment
  labels:
    app: httpd
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpd
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: httpd
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-apache2
        image: docker.io/arunsippy12/my-apache2:latest
        securityContext:
         allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
         capabilities:
          add: ["NET_RAW"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Also u can refer the k8s documentation:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/